# Need help in yii to display two tables data in CGridView?

Tags: php, yii

Need help in yii to display two tables data in CGridView -

Tables info -

**Branch**

```
Id
branch_name
```

**User**

```
Id
branch_id
user_name
```

Relations -

**BranchMaster**

```
public function relations()
  {
    return array(
    'users' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'User', 'branch_id'),  
    );
   }
```

**UserMaster**

```
public function relations()
  {
    return array(
    'branchs' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Branch', 'Id'), 
    );
   }
```

**view.php**

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', 
   array(
      'id'=>'my-grid',
      'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
      'filter'=>$model,
      'columns'=>array(
        'Id',
    'branch_name', 
    array('name'=>'users.user_name', 'value'=>$data->User>user_name),
        ),
));
```

**_view.php**

```
<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('Id')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->Id); ?>
<br />

<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('branch_name')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->branch_name); ?>
<br />

<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('user_name')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->user_name); ?>
<br />
```

I'm getting records fine but user_name always blank value display.
Help me to solve my issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the relation `HAS_ONE` instead of `HAS_MANY`

```
'users' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'User', 'branch_id'),
```

Working fine now!!

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting the value because the $data part is wrong -

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', 
   array(
  'id'=>'my-grid',
  'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
  'filter'=>$model,
  'columns'=>array(
    'Id',
    'branch_name', 
    array(
        'name'=>'users.user_name',
        'value'=>'$data->users->user_name'),     //here you used $data->User and need ' ' too
    ),
));
```

Comment: seriously .down vote for '' ??Real smooth ;) so the answer correct doesn't get anything now does it ? Nice. Maybe if you tried it youd realise that without the '' it dont always work ;)

Comment: because your answer is totally incorrect from what i want exactly. but now my code working fine, Just change the relation HAS_ONE instead of HAS_MANY.

Comment: well i hope it 'will be work always'. and is that now working with my code included in yours ??

Comment: Its a pleasure bru. some advice though. their are instances where the '' are needed, so the '' will never give an error. so better to do it that way and you know it will then always work. =)